# javascript Truncate string after comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I'm looking for a way to remove the comma and all that comes after it in a string, for example:

> important, not so important

I'd like to remove ",not so important"

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do it with [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(','));
```

but you'd have to be sure that a comma is in there (test it before).

Another possibility is to use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
str = str.split(',')[0];
```

this works even without testing beforehand but might perform unnecessary string operations (which is probably negligible on small strings).

Comment: +1, tho you forgot `str.replace(/,.*/,'');` & `str.slice(0,str.indexOf(','));` ;)

Answer (score 5):

http://www.jsfiddle.net/a5SWU/

```
var a = "important, not so important";

a = a.split(",")[0];
```

Comment: this is repeat answer

Comment: @miteshkalal Yeah we probably hit submit pretty fast and Felix most likely didn't have a fiddle until it was edited. This is from 2011, 9 years ago so who knows, Stackoverflow was much different then.