# Obtain part of text in string that occurs before specified text

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript Truncate string before comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971961/javascript-truncate-string-before-comma)

In a javascript variable, a text (string) is stored...

```
var maintext=" This is some random text. This is second sentence. This is third sentence.";
```

Now another variable stores a portion of text of the first variable as shown below

```
var textportion="third sentence.";
```

Now, I want to obtain the text in variable 'maintext' that occurs just before text stored in 'textportion' variable... i.e. in this example, I want to obtain

```
" This is some random text. This is second sentence. This is "
```

How do I obtain this? I would prefer pure JS, but use of libraries like jquery is also acceptable to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
   // find the starting index of the targeted text
var idx = maintext.indexOf(textportion);

     // -1 means no match was found
if (idx !== -1)
    var firstpart = maintext.slice(0, idx); // slice text from start until idx
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/hkJnn/

Comment: Any reason for `slice()` instead of `substring()`?

Comment: @DavidThomas: Habit mostly. Also, I get tired of trying to remember the different behaviors of `substr` and `substring`, and which one has browser bugs, so I just standardize on `.slice()`. It's behavior is the same as the `[].slice()`, so even easier.

Comment: Good reasons, was just wondering if there was a secret performance benefit I hasn't heard about, yet. =)

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
maintext.split(textportion, 1)[0];
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j3kwN/)**